# how can i match two collections in scala by a field equality

Tags: scala, collections

i have this code :

```
case class DataText(name:String)
  val dataModels = Seq(DataText("a.dm"),DataText("b.dm"),DataText("c.dm"),DataText("d.dm"),DataText("e.dm"),DataText("f.dm"))
  val dataReports = Seq(DataText("a.d0"),DataText("b1.do"),DataText("c2.do"),DataText("d.do"),DataText("e3.do"),DataText("f5.do"))
```

how can i match dataModels and dataReports, when an item in dataModels split  by "." like name.split(".").head can match to dataReports split by "." like name.split(".").head

The result could be:

```
Seq(DataText("a.dm"),DataText("d.dm"))
```

i have tried with map and an embedded filter but don't work.

Comment: Consider having two fields in `DataText` rather than just one. So `DataText("a", "dm")` etc. This will make it easier to match on the fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would transform `dataReports` into a `Set` of the target sub-elements for filtering via `contains` (which is a constant time O(1) operation):

```
val dataReportsSet = dataReports.map(_.name.split("\\.")(0)).toSet

dataModels.filter(dm => dataReportsSet.contains(dm.name.split("\\.")(0)))
// res1: Seq[DataText] = List(DataText(a.dm), DataText(d.dm))
```